# Spring Boot Bean Validation for LocatDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation

I have Person POJO where in `private LocalDateTime startTime;` attribute as below,

```
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("startTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

I need to send `"startTime": "2020-08-20T12:30:18+0000",` from my JSON input to a rest end point.

I get bad request, is there anything missing in my validation? I tried with removing `Z` and adding `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ssZ")` also but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Deserializer for LocalDateTime for your desired format and use on field.

```
@NotNull
@JsonDeserialize(using = JacksonLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

Custom Deserializer implementations

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class JacksonLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9152770723354619045L;
  public JacksonLocalDateTimeDeserializer() { this(null);}
  protected JacksonLocalDateTimeDeserializer(Class<LocalDateTime> type) { super(type);}

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (parser.getValueAsString().isEmpty()) {
       return null;
    }
    return LocalDateTime.parse(parser.getValueAsString(),
                                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ```DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constant.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);``` the```Constant.DATE_TIME_FORMAT``` which package?  and use of this?  There is null passed in ```this()```

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constant.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);` is a gitch I remove that, and `this(null)` is default behavior of  `StdDeserializer` implementation. I missunderstood you question first.

Comment: That's fine, no worries. When tried to read the attribute, I am getting ```2020-08-20T12:30:18``` but i wanted to get full value including ```+0000```. i.e. ```2020-08-20T12:30:18+0000```

Comment: LocalDateTime don't store offset data

Comment: Okey fine then i will handle it in other way around. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: @ThangavelLoganathan If you want to store offset data use `ZonedDateTime`

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a ton :-)